# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getHtml'

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I wrote a code in which i used mention below statement

```
editor.insertHtml(paragraph.getOuterHtml());
```

which throws  **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getHtml'**  in chrome.
However when i run my code on firefox i got

```
    TypeError: startNode.getFirst() is null
[Break On This Error]   

...tartNode = startNode.getFirst().insertBeforeMe( range.document.createText( '' ) ...
```

while debug using firebug i found that my code is here which is an inbuild function of ckeditor 5.3

```
 var getNativeListener = function( domObject, eventName )
{
return function( domEvent )
{
// In FF, when reloading the page with the editor focused, it may
// throw an error because the CKEDITOR global is not anymore
// available. So, we check it here first. (#2923)
if ( typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined' )
domObject.fire( eventName, new CKEDITOR.dom.event( domEvent ) );
};
};
```

Now,please tell what will i do to remove an error??

Comment: What is `paragraph`? A native DOM element? A CKEditor element? There's no such thing like "ckeditor 5.3". Latest CKEditor is 4.1.2. So which version do you use?

Comment: The version of the ckeditor is 3.5.Source code of the paragraph is: <p><cdl:metadata fname="VGVAPB+GaramondPremrPro" fsize="10.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="388.04">The introduction in the 1990s of mobile phones using the</cdl:metadata> <cdl:metadata fname="VGVAPB+GaramondPremrPro" fsize="10.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="399.54">digital Global System for Mobile Communications (GSM) with</cdl:metadata></p>. Selection made on the how paragraph so that i am able to insert custom tag just after the start of p tag